# I'm subclassing AlertController and get the error 'UIAlertController must have a title, a message or an action to display'

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uialertcontroller, subclassing

```
final class AlertViewComponent: UIAlertController {

    private(set) var model: Model!
    private let alert: UIAlertController

    init() {

        self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "abc", message: "def", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: L10n.Generic.Label.ok, style: .default, handler: nil))

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configureAlert(options: AlertOption) {

        self.alert.title = self.model.title
        self.alert.message = self.model.message

        switch options {
        case let .oneOption(handler):

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: L10n.Generic.Label.ok, style: .default, handler: handler))

        case let .twoOptions(handlerYes, handlerNo):

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: L10n.Generic.Label.ok, style: .default, handler: handlerYes))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: L10n.Generic.Label.yes, style: .default, handler: handlerNo))
        }
    }
}

extension AlertViewComponent: Component {

    enum AlertOption {

        case oneOption(handler: (UIAlertAction) -> Void)
        case twoOptions(handlerYes: (UIAlertAction) -> Void, handlerNo: (UIAlertAction) -> Void)
    }

    struct Model {

        let title: String
        let message: String

        init(title: String = "", message: String) {

            self.title = title
            self.message = message
        }
    }

    enum Configuration {

        case update(model: Model)
    }

    func render(with configuration: AlertViewComponent.Configuration) {

        switch configuration {
        case let .update(model):

            self.model = model
        }
    }
}
```

I initialise the alert with:

```
private let alertViewComponent: AlertViewComponent = {

    let alertViewComponent = AlertViewComponent()
    alertViewComponent.render(with: .update(model: AlertViewComponent.Model(title: "title", message: "message")))

    return alertViewComponent
}()
```

but when I present the alert, I get the error:

> 'UIAlertController must have a title, a message or an action to
>   display'

Comment: From UIAlertController documentation: `The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`. Might use `extension` instead?

Comment: So your class both `is-a` and `has-a` UIAlertViewController - sounds fishy.

Comment: @Larme I see... guess I will look into it

Comment: @Gereon first I subclassed UIViewController then I changed, but guess this isn't working

Comment: What you really want is to do: `let alert = `UIAlert`.init(withMyCustomModel: model)`, then add an extension for that on `UIAlertController`, no? Or do you want to handle other things too? Which one exactly?

Comment: @Larme yeah, you're right. That's what I want. You should give some kind of answer, so that I would mark it

Answer (score 0):

You never called your `configureAlert` function. Also, you are subclassing and also have an alert controller member. Which one got presented? There is no need to subclass alert controller at all -- just use your member.

Comment: yeah, too much stuff going around that has to be fixed. Don't know if I should mark this answer...